# Java - How to observing another process

Tags: java, process, observable

I have two Java applications. Both applications run the server on a dedicated port.

Application "A" launches application "B" from controller:

```
java.lang.ProcessBuilder() builder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
// ...
java.lang.Process process = builder.start();
```

Next, I need to check that application "B" is running successfully. Now I wait for a certain time and then check exit code.

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
try {
    int exitCode = process.exitValue();
    // We check exit code of the application to find out the shutdown reason.
} catch (IllegalThreadStateException ignored) {
    // Fine, process "B" started.
}
```

This works, however, a startup time longer than 10 seconds may return an incorrect result.

Is there a way to send certain codes or run events from app "B" to read them from app "A"?

For example:

"B"

```
void start() {
    doStuff1();
    sendEvent("Do stuff done");
    doStuff2();
    sendEvent("B is running");
}
```

"A"

```
while(true) {
    String message = readEvent();
    if(message.equals("B is running") {
        // Fine, process "B" started.
    }
}
```

UPD: Application "A" should return response to the client whether it was possible to successfully launch application "B". Application "B" goes through several stages of launch including server startup, bundles initialization, etc. Each of these stages can cause an error and take an indefinite amount of time. Therefore, I need to receive events that happened in application "B" in order to be sure that it started correctly.

Comment: There's the [`Process#onExit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html#onExit()) method, added in Java 9, which returns a `CompletableFuture` that's completed when the process exits. Meaning that as long as the future is not completed then the process is running. I'm not sure if that meets your requirements.

Comment: @user16320675 The problem is that application "A" must return response to the client whether application "B" was started. Application "B" is regularly updated and its launch time is not constant. So, I wanted to avoid timeouts in order to accurately return status of application.

Comment: @Slaw I forgot to mention it in the question. Application "A" should return response to the client whether it was possible to successfully launch application "B". Application "B" goes through several stages of launch including server startup, bundles initialization, etc. Each of these stages can cause an error and take an indefinite amount of time.

Comment: @user16320675 I updated my question. `ProcessBuilder.start()`, in this case, may not return an error. However, one of the startup stages while the application is running may return an error.

Comment: Is it possible to assume that process B started successfully, and only notify the user if the process then later terminates exceptionally? Or does process B provide any feedback as to its current internal state (e.g., printing info to its output, or a way to remotely connect to it, etc.)?

Comment: @Slaw Yes, process "B" provides feedback to process "A". The logic is that the client through application "A" (on port 8080) can launch application "B" (on port 9000). If launch is successful, client can navigate to this address, such as localhost:9000, and open Application "B". If application "B" did not start for some reason, I need to notify client about error. For example, server port 9000 is busy.